Android NavX: Initial backstack
Currently, I am trying to come up with a way to show a list of screens to the user before he reaches the HOME screen.
I am using NavX typeSafe with fragments. I have been investigating the navX apis and so far I can see that there is only one way of adding fragments to the backstack and that is through the navController.navigate api.
Example:
Lets say that when the user enters the app, we run some logic that determines what screens he should see before the HOME screen is presented. That means that the initial screens are not fixed. Those screens can be an intro screen, a login screen, whatever.
Do you know if there is an api or way to accomplish this?
